# LSOpenURLsWithRole fails when opening App from command line

Tags: macos

I'm getting the below error when opening an .app from the Application folder.

```
open /Applications/Spark.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Spark.app
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this one?

Comment: where did u compiling the code (OS)

Comment: Trying to open an app via a sh script on OSX, via php.